# Where does windows server 2003 store its network connection information

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, networking

Where does windows server store its netowrk connection information and would I be able to edit this information by mounting the drive under linux and editing the information?

I may need to do this because I have a server running windows server 2003 that's network connection got screwed up and the machine does not have any video support and I can't access the system remotely to make the changes

Answer (score 1):

Those informations are stored in the Registry.

If you want to try this route, you need to mount the server's disk under a ***Windows*** machine and open its Registry using REGEDIT.

There's no way you can do that in a Linux system.

The network configuration is stored in HKLM\System\ControlSetX\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\GUID

Where **ControlSetX** is the running ControlSet of the system (you need to find the right one) and **GUID** is the unique ID of the network interface you need to edit.

Comment: BTW, the text formattng seems to go really awry if you mix control code (asterisks) and backslashes in the same line... I tried to write ControlSetX and GUID in **bold**, and the preview looked good, but the published answer **didn't**.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it on a network with other computer. And sniff for its IP with wireshark.

Comment: But maybe its network interface is disabled altogether... an erroneous right-click on a network interface has cost me more than a trip to the server room.

Comment: how would I sniff its ip out. I'd like to at least give this a try before taking everything apart

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this information in Linux using the regedit program in Wine or the command line program chntpw. Massimo has the actual registry keys covered so I won't go there.